# Django Debug Toolbar in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

How can I use Django Debug Toolbar in Heroku when I don't know the IP address so this:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1', )
```

Always fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on Daniel Roseman's answer, here is how to have the toolbar show for staff users:
Assign dotted path to the function to SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK

settings.py:

```
def show_toolbar(request):
    return request.user.is_staff

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    # ...
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'project.settings.show_toolbar',
}
```

Comment: I did something like this when I had the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I have the following in my settings.py, which works both locally and when I deploy to Heroku:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  ...
  'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware'
 ...
)

if DEBUG is True:
   INSTALLED_APPS += (
       'debug_toolbar',
       )

if DEBUG is True:
  class AllIPS(list):
      def __contains__(self, item):
           return True
  INTERNAL_IPS = AllIPS()
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no dependency on INTERNAL_IPS to show the debug toolbar. That's simply the default way of ensuring that you only show it to your actual developers. As the documentation explains, you can provide your own logic for this by defining a function a setting `SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK` to point to that function. So, for example, you could check for a certain username, or simply return True to ensure it's always shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could put `{{ request.META.REMOTE_ADDR }}` in your template and see the IP DJDT wants to see in `INTERNAL_IPS`. [Documentation about request.META](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META).

Comment: This won't work for heroku pipelines - in my case - every time I deploy - the IP got changed, but nice hint though.

Comment: Do you really need this on your production host ?

Comment: It's not the deployment IP, it's YOUR ip that it wants !

Comment: I know, I tried 1st mine own and then tried heroku server (that is changing all the time) - none worked - when I did TAH's answer - all worked nicely, I know toolbar should not be on production - but this site is not live yet and I could not find why the site is loading slower even debugging localhost, when I have achieved that toolbar is on production, it immediately helped me to pin-point the problem and now it is fixed and toolbar is gone from production :) thank you for help